# Finder sidebar duplicating entries

Tags: finder, preferences

I'm trying to figure out why one of my drives is appearing multiple times in the Finder sidebar.
If I drag the list order a new one is generated. Dragging out to the desktop, the normal way of deleting them, fails; it simply reappears immediately in the sidebar.

[image]

From [georgegarside blog - Mac Finder Sidebar Favourites Location](https://georgegarside.com/blog/macos/finder-sidebar-preferences-location/) I discovered the names & locations of the two files possibly responsible.
`~/Library/Preferences/com.apple.finder.plist`
`~/Library/Preferences/com.apple.sidebarlists.plist`

I tried throwing them away, but that was considerably more trouble than it was worth, as defaulting the Finder views entirely is just too much work to put back how I like it.

The .plist files themselves look pretty complex, so I'm trying to figure out what I can safely delete to see if will restore normailty.

Answer (score 2):

As I had backups of everything I decided to play fast & loose with copies of the two .plist files.

I dropped both files into [BBEdit](https://apps.apple.com/us/app/bbedit/id404009241?mt=12) & tried to make sense of the reams of data.
The sidebar file looked at a glance more promising so I started with that.

I realised it had several thousand aliases to disk drives, SD Cards, CDs, RAMDisks & disk images permanent & temporary, dating back over perhaps a decade.

[image]

Carefully selecting sections from `<dict>` to `</dict>` in each case, I deleted all aliases except the one that contained `SeenAsBootVolume`. Saved & relogged.

Success. The current list rebuilt itself, the myriad 'spares' were gone & the drive no longer duplicates if I move/drag items in the list.

As a hint as to just how many old drive aliases I did actually delete -  the file was 82MB… it is now 9KB.

[image]

<sup>…and, no, the date modified on the older one doesn't make any sense to me either;)</sup>

Comment: Which file did you edit, and how? :-)

Comment: @nohillside - files listed in question now, details added to answer